# Grep find pattern but print another line

Tags: grep

I want to match all cyrillic characters, but print the ID to file. For example:

```
Author: Doe, John
Title: Оптимизация ресурсного потенциала промышленности города с учетом его конкурентных преимуществ
ID: 1234567
```

My current approach is to grep for cyrillic characters:

```
grep -i -r --include=*{rdf,redif,rdf~} --color="auto" -P -n '[\x{0400}-\x{04FF}]' > cyrillic.txt
```

How can I just print the ID line to a file and not the matching line?

Answer (score 0):

Use `-A1` option if the `ID:` line is right after the matching pattern. Then pipe it to another `grep` to get the line with `ID:`.

```
 grep -A1 -i -r --include=*{rdf,redif,rdf~} --color="auto" -P -n '[\x{0400}-\x{04FF}]' \
 | grep 'ID: ' > cryllic.txt
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I was vaguely phrasing that. 'ID' could be somewhere in the file, it's not always following the 'title' string.

Comment: Then why don't you use just `grep 'ID: ' inputfile`.

Comment: I have a set of n files, and only some of them contain cyrillic chars. So first I have to grep for the unicode character codes.

Answer (score 0):

Use grep flag `h` - to suppress output file names - you'll have output like:

```
4:string with matching pattern
5:string with matching pattern
7:string with matching pattern
```

Now you can pipe this output into `awk` and print only fist column, which is matching string number:

```
{your_grep} | awk -F ':' '{print $1}' > cyrillic.txt
```